# QML RegExpValidator maximum string length for validation

Tags: regex, qt, qml

I am a novice at QML and Qt Quick, with just 5 days ago that I came to know of them.
I intended to have a RegExpValidator for a TextInput of comma separated words, the total input string length allowed from 1-2500.

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    width : 100
    height : 50

    Text {
        id : label
        text: "Enter words"
    }

    TextInput {
        anchors {
            topMargin : 5
            top : label.bottom
        }
        focus: true
        validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /[a-zA-Z,]{1,2500}/ }
     }
}
```

is my RegExpValidator_example.qml file, which won't accept any input.
By trial and error I found out that the upper limit for the regExp length is 1024
that is,

```
validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /[a-zA-Z,]{1,1024}/ }
```

works, but

```
validator: RegExpValidator { regExp: /[a-zA-Z,]{1,1025}/ }
```

doesn't. So I found another way :

```
maximumLength: 2500
validator : RegExpValidator { regExp : /[a-zA-Z,]{1,}/ }
```

I tried searching the QML documentation for the mention of the upper limit, but to no avail. Have I really failed searching, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went throughout the documentation of `RegExpValidator` as well as the one of `QRegExp`, that is its C++ counterpart, in other terms the class that is instantiated under the hood.

As you said, there is no clue of a limit.

Curious about, I went to look over the [source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp?h=5.5) and I found that actually the limit exists. It is set to `InftyRep` and used [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp?h=5.5#n3475) (of course, if I've been able enough to understand what's happening in that file). Curiously, `InftyRep` is actually set to 1025 [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp?h=5.5#n698) and used in the code above mentioned in a check with `<`. That's would also confirm your suggestion that the max accepted length is `1024`.

That said, I strongly suspect that you are right, for the limit actually exists, but it is not properly documented.

*Note*: The code above mentioned and linked is the one of Qt 5.5 and you might consider to open an issue on the [bugtracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: Thank you for directing towards the source code. I've reported the issue on the Qt Bug Tracker : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49319

Comment: Well, I had opened the issue asking to document the limit rather than to change it. :-)

Comment: It can validate greater than 1024 length strings. So why limit?

Comment: The folks from the QtProject are skilled, if a limit exists, a reason for it must exist as well. Anyway, they will reply to your ticket and give the right suggestion, no doubt about it.